# Safe way to json a html?

Tags: javascript, html, json

My question is pretty simple, I would like to recreate a html page with json,
but I do not want to mess with existing html, framework and co...

Example :

```
var myDiv = { tag : "div", style : "color:blue", class : "jj", content : "Hello"};
```

```js
var myDiv = { tag : "div", style : "color:blue", class : "jj", content : "Hello"};
var param = { forbid : { tag : true, content : true } };
var createTag = function(o) {

    var node = document.createElement(o.tag);
    for (att in o) {
      if (!param.forbid[att]) node.setAttribute(att, o[att]);
    }
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.content))
    return node;

}


document.body.textContent = createTag(myDiv).outerHTML;
```

the result of this code is  :

```
<div style="color:blue" class="jj"> Hello </div>
```

How can I be sure that "tag" and "content" doesn't mess with existing/future attributes?
And keep it simple?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this, rather than just write the HTML?

Comment: check out hoquet https://github.com/tjb1982/hoquet maybe this is what you need.

Comment: This seems like the very definition of "not simple".

Comment: Please include the code that you've tried in your question and what problems you've had with it. As it stands this is a "give me teh codez" style question and should either be closed as too broad or [off-topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for not having a [mcve].

Comment: @zzzzBov I've just had a working snippet

Answer (score 9):

To avoid conflicts with attributes, I would keep them separated

```
var myDiv = {
  tagName: "div",
  attributes: {
    style: "color: blue",
    class: "jj"
  },
  childNodes: ["Hello"]
};
```

```js
function parseTree(node) {
  if(typeof node === 'string') // Text node
    return document.createTextNode(node);
  // Otherwise, assuming an element. Consider adding
  // `node.nodeType` if you want multiple node types
  var el = document.createElement(node.tagName);
  if(node.hasOwnProperty('attributes'))
    for(var attr in node.attributes)
      if(node.attributes.hasOwnProperty(attr))
        el.setAttribute(attr, node.attributes[attr]);
  if(node.hasOwnProperty('childNodes'))
    node.childNodes.forEach(function(child) {
      el.appendChild(parseTree(child));
    });
  return el;
}
document.body.textContent = parseTree({
  tagName: "div",
  attributes: {
    style: "color: blue",
    class: "jj"
  },
  childNodes: ["Hello"]
}).outerHTML;
```

Alternatively, you could use strings with some characters not allowed in attribute names. For example, `\u0000` or .

```
var myDiv = {
  " tagName": "div",
  style: "color: blue",
  class: "jj",
  " childNodes": ["Hello"]
};
```

```js
function parseTree(node) {
  if(typeof node === 'string') // Text node
    return document.createTextNode(node);
  // Otherwise, assuming an element. Consider adding
  // `node[" nodeType"]` if you want multiple node types
  var el = document.createElement(node[" tagName"]);
  for(var attr in node)
    if(node.hasOwnProperty(attr) && attr[0] !== " ")
      el.setAttribute(attr, node[attr]);
  if(node[" childNodes"])
    node[" childNodes"].forEach(function(child) {
      el.appendChild(parseTree(child));
    });
  return el;
}
document.body.textContent = parseTree({
  " tagName": "div",
  style: "color: blue",
  class: "jj",
  " childNodes": ["Hello"]
}).outerHTML;
```

Comment: yes, i've thought about that, but it's to too complicated for my framework with a hundred of myDiv, included themselves each an other

Comment: @alexino2 It's the 0only option if you want to allow arbitrary attributes.

Comment: parseTree is more or less what i use to convert it into html, but just the fact of using "attributes : {}" make things safe of course, but not simple....

Comment: image now a  p1.p2.myDiv.attributes.style = "" ... is more complicated rather than a  p1.p2.myDiv.style = ""

Comment: @Oriol but the op is asking for a way to load from json

Comment: @Oriol Symbol seems pretty nice but it's ES6, and doesn't seem compatible with advanced minify (it hates strings). I think that i'll stick with attributes in the end.... which is more universal. Thanks again

Comment: @penne12 Of course, symbols are not useful here. That's what happens when I attempt to improve an answer but I'm too sleepy. Thanks

Comment: @Oriol Lol - don't worry about it :D

Comment: @Oriol : about your second answer :  myDiv. tagName = "div";  just results a <div tagName="div"> And myDiv[" tagName"] = "div" works but it's not pretty :) your first answer seems the (only?) best way.

Comment: @alexino2 Note the space before the property. In the parser I check `attr[0] !== " "` to filter these out.

Comment: @Oriol correct,, my bad... but it doesn't solve the direct access myDiv. tagName = "div"; without string.

Comment: @alexino2 That would be `myDiv[" tagName"] = "div"`. It needs quotes and brackets.

Comment: @Oriol yep, as I said, but it's not pretty : imagine to deal with string when a hard minify will not reduce it to only one letter, or when other users (or me) will forget about the space or quotes... Using attributes {} is not so bad in the end.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this, if you'd like:

```
["div", {style: "color:blue", class: "jj"}, ["Hello"]]
```

With an inner element, you'd do:

```
["div", {style: "color:blue", class: "jj"}, [[
  "p",
  "hello"
]]]
```

Here's the parsing code (just the `parseTree` function) - I also added a way to try it out (and the HTML was written with the json-based format as an example)

```js
html = ["div", [["div",
  [
    ["p", ["Try it out:"]],
    [
      "code", {
        id: "try",
        style: "display:block",
        contentEditable: true
      },
      ['["div", { style: "color:blue;", class: "jj"}, ["Hello"]]']
    ],
    ["button", {
        "onclick": "return tryOut();"
      },
      ["Run"]
    ]
  ]
],["div", {id: "result-wrapper"}]]]

window.tryOut = function() {
  var el = parseTree(eval(document.querySelector("code#try").innerText));
  var holder = document.createElement("div");
  holder.appendChild(el);
  document.querySelector("#result-wrapper").innerHTML = holder.innerHTML;
}

document.body.appendChild(parseTree(html));


function parseTree(tree) {
  if (typeof tree === 'string') {
    return document.createTextNode(tree);
  }

  var el = document.createElement(tree[0]),
    attrs, simple, inner;

  if (tree.length == 2) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree[1])) {
      inner = tree[1];
    } else {
      attrs = tree[1];
    }
  } else if (tree.length == 3) {
    attrs = tree[1];
    inner = tree[2];
  } else {
    simple = true;
  }

  if (!simple) {
    if (attrs) {
      for (var attr in attrs)
        if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
          console.log(attr)
          console.log(attrs[attr])
          el.setAttribute(attr, attrs[attr]);
        }
    }
    if (inner) {
      inner.forEach(function(child) {
        el.appendChild(parseTree(child));
      });
    }
  }

  return el;
}

if (!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
  };
}
```